# producing barplots with single color and multiple shades in R

Tags: r

I wish to produce barplots in R with one color per bar, but multiple shades for this color within the same bar. 
For example I tried:

```
barplot(c(2:6), ylim=c(1,10), col="blue", space=3)
```

this gives me blue color bars, but I want the top region to appear slightly lighter blue compared to bottom region.

I also tried:

```
barplot(c(2:6), ylim=c(1,10), col="blue", space=3,density=40)
```

but this is not what I wish as it again gives a constant appearance throughout the plot

Answer (score 2):

This comes from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17460/what-is-the-best-way-to-visualize-a-single-numeric-variable-as-a-heatmap

I only just found this but I think this might be useful.

```
require(fields)
plot(1:10, rep(1,10), ylim=c(0,10))
 colorbar.plot( 2, 4, 800*density(rgamma(100, shape=2))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 5, 800*density(rexp(100))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 6, 800*density(rnorm(100))$y)
 colorbar.plot( 2, 7, 800*density(rlnorm(100))$y)
 text(6,4, "Gamma")
 text(6,5, "Exponential")
 text(6,6, "Normal")
 text(6,7, "LogNormal")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
barplot(c(2:6), ylim=c(1,10), col="blue", space=3, density=seq(60, 100, 10))
```

or

```
barplot(c(2:6), ylim=c(1,10), col=blues9[2:6], space=3)
```

Comment: in your second command, I wish to have each bar containing all 5 variations of color blues9.

Comment: @Munish Sorry I didn't read your question carefully. IMHO a color gradient in one bar isn't possible with default graphics.

Comment: @sgibb  I didn't know either of your methods and while it's not what the poster wanted +1.  I'm curious on the second code chunk how to extend that to other colors besides blue.  I tried `barplot(c(2:6), ylim=c(1,10), col=grays9[2:6], space=3)` for fun but didn't work.

Comment: @TylerRinker `blues9` is a vector containing 9 RGB codes for blue colors. IMHO `grays9` doesn't exist. But you could use `?gray` instead (`barplot(2:6, col=gray(level=seq(0, 1, length.out=5)), space=3)`). Or try `colors()`: `barplot(2:6, col=colors()[3:7], space=3)`